# Kotlin Room Database Save Control

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I save data to Room database with a button. However, every time I press the button, that item is registered and listed again and again. I want to write a control. I do not want it to save it if it is registered. I will be glad if you help.

> ArticleDao

```
@Dao
interface ArticleDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsert(article: Article): Long
```

> NewsRepisotry

```
class NewsRepository(
    val db: ArticleDatabase
) {

    suspend fun  upsert(article: Article)=db.getArticleDao().upsert(article)

    fun getSavedNews()=db.getArticleDao().getAllArticles()
```

> ArticleDatabase

```
@Database(
    entities = [Article::class],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ArticleDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getArticleDao(): ArticleDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: ArticleDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            instance ?: createDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }

        private fun createDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                ArticleDatabase::class.java,
                "article_db.db"
            ).build()
    }
}
```

> Article.kt

@Entity(
tableName = "articles"
)

```
data class  Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var Id: Int? = null,
    val author: String?,
    val content: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    val source: Source?,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?
) : Serializable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue would appear to be that `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` is inserting instead of replacing.

The **OnConflict** strategy will only be actioned **if there is a conflict**. That is typically that a **UNIQUE constraint is violated** *(see link below for other violations covered)*.

From your explanation of the issue there is no violation and thus instead of the row(s) being replaced, they are instead inserted.

- You may wish to refere to https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

In short you need a **UNIQUE index** to cover your scenario to ensure that a violation occurs.

Without the Article class it is impossible to say what actual change is required. However the following example shows 2 classes (entities) and how a unique index can be added to a column/property **articleName**.

So first a **guess** as what your Article class could be:-

```
@Entity
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey
    var articelId: Long? = null,
    var articleName: String,
    var otherData: String
)
```

and here an equivalent with a UNIQUE index on the articleName property/column :-

```
@Entity(indices = [Index(value = ["articleName"],unique = true)])
data class ArticleV2(
    @PrimaryKey
    var articleId: Long? = null,
    var articleName: String,
    var otherData: String
)
```

**Example/Demo**

As an example of how both work differently, the latter according to your expectations, consider the following code, utilising the above, (for brevity/convenience run on the main thread) :-

The `@Dao` **ArticleDao** for both tables/entiities/classes :-

```
@Dao
interface ArticleDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun upsert(article: Article): Long

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun upsert(articleV2: ArticleV2)

    @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM article")
    fun getArticleCount(): Long

    @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM articlev2")
    fun getArticleV2Count(): Long
}
```

The `@Database` **ArticleDatabase** class :-

```
@Database(
    entities = [Article::class, ArticleV2::class],
    version = 1
)

abstract class ArticleDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getArticleDao(): ArticleDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: ArticleDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            instance ?: createDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }

        private fun createDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                ArticleDatabase::class.java,
                "article_db.db"
            )
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
    }
}
```

Finally an activity, that replicates your *"every time I press the button"* by looping 5 times inserting one row into each table per iteration and then after the loop writing the number of rows in each of the tables to the log.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: ArticleDatabase
    lateinit var dao: ArticleDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = ArticleDatabase.invoke(this)
        dao = db.getArticleDao()

        for(i in 1..5) {
            dao.upsert(Article(null, "Article", "otherdata$i"))
            dao.upsert(ArticleV2(null,"Article","otherdata$i"))
        }
        Log.d("ARTICLECOUNT","Number of Articles in article table = " + dao.getArticleCount() + "... in articleV2 table = " + dao.getArticleV2Count())
    }
}
```

When run (first time) the output in the log contains:-

```
D/ARTICLECOUNT: Number of Articles in article table = 5... in articleV2 table = 1
```

So 5 rows inserted into the article table but only 1 row in the articleV2 table (as the value used for the articleName is the same).

After running Database Inspector shows :-

The **article** table

[image]

The **articleV2** table

[image]

- As can be seen the otherData column has been replaced throughout and is otherdata5
- If the OnConflict strategy were IGNORE then otherData would have a value of otherdata1

---

**Additional**

regarding the comment and Article class now added.

> First of all, thank you sir. I have also added the Article class. Your explanation is very good, but I could not understand exactly what I needed to change.

You need to decide what constitutes a duplicate entry.

Perhaps the URL if unchanged could be the most likely to indicate a duplicate.

So you could use :-

```
@Entity( tableName = "articles", indices = [Index(value = ["url"],unique = true)] ) //<<<<<<<<< ONLY CHANGE IS THE @Entity
data class  Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var Id: Int? = null,
    val author: String?,
    val content: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    val source: Source?,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?
) : Serializable
```

- thus a UNIQUE index (one that does not allow the same value to be stored more than once) would be created and maintained on the url column.

  - Note NULL is not considered a duplicate value (that is a NULL is considered to be different to any other NULL), so if this value can be null then perhaps it is not a wise choice.

However, you may decide that multiple columns should constitute a duplicate to not be inserted. Here's a variation showing how multiple columns (composite index) can be used.

```
@Entity( tableName = "articles", indices = [Index(value = ["author","content","description"],unique = true)] ) //<<<<<<<<< ONLY CHANGE IS THE @Entity
data class  Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var Id: Int? = null,
    val author: String?,
    val content: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    val source: Source?,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?
) : Serializable
```

- in this case if the author, content and description were the same then it would be a duplicate.

**Note** in all cases allowing all null values *(`?` after all)* could be problematic if there is no validation to stop all values being null *(i.e. the data would probably be useless)*.

You may also wish to consider clearing inputs (some only perhaps) after an insertion, thus making it less likely for a duplicate to be attemtped.

Comment: First of all, thank you sir. I have also added the Article class. Your explanation is very good, but I could not understand exactly what I needed to change.

Comment: @MertKavrayıcı I have updated the answer *(see **Additional** at the end)*, but in the end you have to decide exactly what needs to change as that it is a design issue as to what should be considered a valid Article to add or reject.

Comment: Solved the problem, sir. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's because the schema has changed. If you can lose the data just uninstall the App.